# Getting JSON and cross to another class in AsyckTask

Tags: android

I'm trying to receive `JSON` from sever and continue to another class, but can't, not working, this how to look my code

class when I click button:

```
public void onHistoryCheckIn(View view) {
  String nCar = numberCar; // to send number car for receive all data json
  String type = "historyChckIn";
  PreHistoryCheckIn preHistoryCheckIn = new PreHistoryCheckIn(this);
  preHistoryCheckIn.execute(type,nCar); // send the data to recieve json 
}
```

Know I go to `doInBackground`, and I use the `onPostExecute`

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
  // jsonResult ==> I NEED THE DATA!!!
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, HistoryCheckIn.class); // have Damage
  context.startActivity(intent);
  // alertDialog.setMessage(jsonResult);
  // alertDialog.show();
}
```

I come to class `HistoryCheckIn` but without `JSON`, what I can do?

I want to bring `jsonResult` and I want to come to HistoryCheckIn.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the result as an extra to the `Intent` e.g.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, HistoryCheckIn.class);
    intent.putExtra("result", s);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

and retrieve it by calling in `HistoryCheckIn`

```
String jsonResult = getIntent().getStringExtra("result");
```

Comment: user is already in `History` class see `onHistoryCheckIn` it requires a callback mechanism ,rest u know what this code do

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way is to add json to your inent

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
   Intent i =new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("json", s)
   context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

on other end call

```
String s= getIntent().getStringExtra("json");
```

but it is not the best way